# BeautifulSoup invalid syntax in Python 3.4 (after 2to3.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

I am trying to install Beautiful Soup 4 in Python 3.4. I installed it from the command line, (got the invalid syntax error because I had not converted it), ran the `2to3.py` conversion script to `bs4` and now I get a new invalid syntax error.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Python34\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Python34\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Python34\bs4\element.py", line 1213
    print 'Running CSS selector "%s"' % selector
                                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BeautifulSoup 4 does **not** need manual converting to run on Python 3. You are trying to run code only compatible with Python 2 instead; it appears you failed to correctly convert the codebase.

From the [BeautifulSoup 4 homepage](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

> Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3.

The line now throwing the exception *should* read:

```
print('Running CSS selector "%s"' % selector)
```

The codebase does use Python 2 syntax, but the `setup.py` installer converts this for you to compatible Python 3 syntax. Make sure to install the project with `pip`:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or using the `pip` version bundled with Python 3.4:

```
python3.4 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or using `easy_install`:

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

If you downloaded just the tarball, *at the very least* run

```
python3.4 setup.py install
```

to have the installer correctly convert the codebase for you; the converted code is *copied into your Python setup*. You can discard the downloaded source directory after running the command, see [*How installation works*](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#how-installation-works).

Alternatively, run:

```
python3.4 setup.py build
```

and copy across the `build/lib` directory. Again, do **not** use the original source directory as it is left untouched.

Comment: I originally converted it, because I was getting an invalid syntax error for the `except Exception, e:` line. Many people have encountered it and in the BeautifulSoup website it is mentioned that bs should be converted.
I tried re-installing it, and now I get the `except Exception, e:` invalid syntax problem again.

Comment: @lenakmeth: there are no `except Exception, e` lines in a correctly installed BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 that I can find. How did you install the library?

Comment: @lenakmeth: I looked a little deeper. The original source does include that syntax, but the installer (`setup.py`) takes care of these details for you. Don't try to convert the codebase on your own.