# Why do I get this error when I try to pip install BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to download BeautifulSoup for my personal needs but when I try to install it, it gives me this:

```
C:\>pip install beautifulsoup
Collecting beautifulsoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ANONYM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-a46azl8h\beautifulsoup\setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ANONYM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-a46azl8h\beautifulsoup\
```

Can anyone help me with installing this? (and yes, beautifulsoup is in my C:)
I am currently using Python 3.6.0, the latest version. Thanks

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140034/beautifulsoup-invalid-syntax-in-python-3-4-after-2to3-py).

Comment: you have to install beautifulsoup4 for python 3

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: oh, thanks. someone told me it was just beautifulsoup